# Event does not fire?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create an imagebutton in code behind like this:

```
ImageButton img1 = new ImageButton();
img1.CssClass = "stylImage";
img1.ImageUrl = @"~/images/Workflow/esign.jpg";
img1.AlternateText = "Signature";
img1.CommandName = "edit";
img1.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(Image_OnClientClick);
img1.Command += new CommandEventHandler(Image_OnCommand);
workdesk.Controls.Add(img1);
```

The button create and display on page, but none of the click or command event fire.
There is no error or exception too.

Any ideas?!?

Comment: Can you show us the image button html when the page is rendered?

Comment: @ JLC007 : sorry but I'm a new programmer, so i don't know how should i do this!

Comment: @ Nikhil Agrawal: there is no problem in postback. i write that code in page load, and when i trace it, it works well, just event does not fire.

Comment: @maryammohammadi What is `workdesk` in your code..?

Comment: @Vishal Suthar workdesk is a div:  <div id="workdesk" class="stylRow" runat="server" >

Comment: @Monkieboy sorry but as i said i'm a new programmer. How can i get the html code?!

Comment: @maryammohammadi Press `Ctrl+U` on your browser to view the HTML code.

Comment: @Vishal Suthar  this is the html code :    <input type="image" name="dnn$ctr464$ViewWorkflowStatus$ctl00" class="stylImage" src="/iccp/images/Workflow/esign.jpg" alt="Signature" style="border-width:0px;" /><a class="verticalitem">Sales</a><img class="stylImageNext" src="/iccp/images/Workflow/left.png" alt="Down" style="border-width:0px;" />

Comment: Is it also contains `<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE4NzI1Nzk0NTNkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBQVjdGwwMmDb8ReUk+hzQRPXezpC7/GxaQzq" />
</div>

<div>

 <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgLPj+azBwKfwImNCwhDqfRXjX/6IAFyRlFdv0ckIamJ" />
</div>`

Comment: @VishalSuthar Suthar  : Yes, it has. what is the problem?!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine and both the events fires perfectly as I tested.

There may be a chance that you have not specified the `Event Definition` correctly.

Please recheck the below code which works like a charme..!!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton img1 = new ImageButton();
    img1.CssClass = "stylImage";
    img1.ImageUrl = @"~/images/Workflow/esign.jpg";
    img1.AlternateText = "Signature";
    img1.CommandName = "edit";
    img1.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(Image_OnClientClick);
    img1.Command += new CommandEventHandler(Image_OnCommand);
    form1.Controls.Add(img1);

}

protected void Image_OnClientClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //some code...
}

protected void Image_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //some code...
}
```

This may help you..!!

Comment: i do write the event definition. How can i expect firing an event when that does not exist!!! i wonder why they don't fire.